# Neat probability puzzle

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

There are $20$ coloured balls of various colours in a bag, such that if you pick two balls at random the chance that the two chosen balls match in colour is $50\%$.

What does the arrangement of the twenty coloured balls need to be? For example there might be 'a' of one colour, 'b' of a second colour, 'c' of a third colour etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you made up this problem yourself ?

Comment: The easiest approach I can think of is brute force with a program.  There is a solution.  Finding it is an elementary exercise in programming `for` loops which I leave to you to practice on your own.

Comment: @trueblueanil Yes I made it up myself some time ago.

Comment: If you insist on doing it by hand, then notice that if there are 15 balls of the most common color, the probability of a match is at least $\frac{15\cdot 14}{20\cdot 19}>0.5$ by ignoring matches of other colors.  Meanwhile if there are at most 12 balls of the most common color, the probability would be at most $\frac{12\cdot 11+8\cdot 7}{20\cdot 19}<0.5$.  This narrows the search range to having $13$ or $14$ of the most common color, there are only a handful of possibilities left, one of which works.

Comment: @Community : This question is perfectly clear and well-defined. Moreover, it is more interesting than most homework exercises in elementary probability.

Comment: @JohnBentin you do realize that Community is a bot, right?  It may have acted upon something someone else said in review or picked up on other bits to decide to post that copy-paste message.  In any event, the OP has not shown any effort.  If they were the one to come up with the problem and they have the solution already, this is not what this site is for.  If they were the one to come up with the problem without knowing if there was a solution, that seems highly suspicious.  I don't believe the OP came up with the problem at all and that this is contest related or something...

Comment: Good math problems are written with the solution in mind first, and the problem is written so as to have that solution.  With all that in mind, I believe my hints so far to already be too strong in the event the OP is lying.  If OP is telling the truth and already has the solution, then they should post it already instead of leaving the question open.  In either event, this question does not deserve to remain open given the level of effort by the OP shown.

Comment: People should look up the first hit from an internet search for “Elliott Line” before insinuating that he is a lazy liar.

Comment: @JohnBentin, so what? Why should anyone do a search for the proposer? He has to show the effort himself and ask a question that's properly formulated.

Comment: @JohnBentin you are extremely gullible if you think the OP is actually Elliot Line.  There would have been zero reason to post this question here if that were the case except perhaps for some advertising of their page... The real Elliot Line [already solved the problem](http://www.elliottline.com/puzzles-1/2022/5/16/solution-of-the-week-365-twenty-coloured-balls).  My expectation is that the OP was given a copy of this and other problems and the original author's name... and they liked the problem set enough to copy the name as their username here.  They aren't doing the name justice however.

Comment: @JohnBentin the writing style and presentation of the problem is all off too, further insinuating that they are not the same person.  Yes, I am insinuating the OP is a lazy liar, and am thoroughly convinced of this, especially after having looked deeper.

Comment: @JMoravitz : Well, you may be right that the OP is impersonating the real Elliott Line, and I am wrong to defend him or her. However, the motivation of such a person, in the present context, would be sufficiently beyond my comprehension for me to disregard the possibility of such an event. Perhaps I am indeed, as you say, extremely gullible.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes I am the real Elliott Line. I too would struggle to understand the motivation of someone pretending to be me!

Comment: @JohnBentin I am in fact the real Elliott Line. I'm new to Maths Stack Exchange however, and I guess I have fundamentally misunderstood what the purpose of this site is. As SIGSec and editor of Enigma (a puzzle SIG for international Mensa), and as the author of all of the 300+ 'Puzzle of the Week' puzzles at elliottline.com, I love to create maths and logic puzzles, and to share them via Enigma, via my website, etc. I didn't realise you couldn't post on this site if you already know the answer!

Comment: [Proof I am he](www.elliottline.com/puzzles-1/2022/8/24/maths-stack-exchange-identity-crisis)

Comment: You can post questions if you know the answer... but if you do so then you should *also post the answer*.  [can I answer my own question if I knew the answer before asking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking?noredirect=1&lq=1).  The purpose of doing so should not explicitly be advertising of your website and books.  [limits for self-promotion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers).

Comment: I apologize that I jumped to conclusions about your identity, but it still makes no sense to me *why* you chose to post the question here in the first place and not your solution as well.  If you are doing it to see how other people approach the solution, fine.  If you don't want them to see your solution if they don't want to before they are ready, use spoiler quotes `>!`.  In the end, I am but one opinionated person sharing this space with many others who are welcome to disagree with how the space is used, but what I have opinions on make sense at least to me to have said opinions.

Comment: The **complete** list of types of question not to ask on this site is copied here:

Don't ask about...

    Anything not directly related to math,
    Questions that are primarily opinion-based,
    Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer,
    Physics, engineering and financial questions,
    Questions about typesetting equations,
    Numerology questions,
    Questions about the site itself — please ask on meta instead. $${}$$ There is nothing here that would exclude your question. I am sorry that you got such an unwelcoming reception.

Answer (score 3):

Since the total number of couples of balls is $190$, the condition to satisfy is
$$\sum_i \binom{k_i}{2}=95$$
where $k_i$ is the number of balls of the $i$-th colour. We can assume $k_1 \geq k_2 \geq k_3 \geq ...$

As it has been pointed out by JMoravitz in the comments, we can only have $13$ or $14$ balls of the most common colour. Consider the case where they are $13$: here the maximum number of pairs with the same colour (excluded the case $k_2=7$, which gives $\binom{13}{2}+\binom{7}{2}=99$ such couples) is achieved with $6$ balls of the second colour and $1$ of the third colour, and it is:
$$\binom{13}{2}+\binom{6}{2}+\binom{1}{2}=93$$
So we must have $k_1=14$. Note that with the values $k_2=3$, $k_3=2$, $k_4=1$ we have exactly
$$\binom{14}{2}+\binom{3}{2}+\binom{2}{2}+\binom{1}{2}=95$$
Finally note that $k_2$ must be at least $3$ since
$$\binom{14}{2}+\binom{2}{2}+\binom{2}{2}+\binom{2}{2}=94$$
Therefore (14, 3, 2,1) is the only acceptable combination for the values of the $k_i$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that of partitioning $20$ as $a_1+\cdots+a_n=20$ so that $\sum_{k=1}^na_k(a_k-1)=190$. Following from @JMorovitz' comment, it suffices to consider only $a_1=13$ and $a_1=14$. All but one of the few possibilities are easily eliminated, leaving $a_1=14$, $a_2=3$, $a_3=2$, and $a_4=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Okay... so the total number of combinations of two balls is $\frac {20\cdot 19}{2} = 190$.

If there are $k$ different colors (not counting the singleton colors) and $n_k$ balls of color $k$ then there are $\sum_{j=1}^k \frac {n_k(n_k-1)}2$ combinations of pairs of balls of the same color.  So we need:

$\frac {\sum_{j=1}^k \frac {n_k(n_k-1)}2}{190} = \frac 12$ or in other words we need

$\sum_{j=1}^k n_k(n_k -1) = 190$.

We also need $\sum_{j=1}^k n_k \le 20$.

The possible values of $n_j(n_j-1)$ are $2,6, 12, 20, 30, 42,56,72,90, 110,132,156$ and $182$

... hmmph...

$190=182+8 = 182 + 6 + 2$.  That would require $14$ of one color ($14\cdot 13 = 182$) and $3$ of another ($3\cdot 2 =6$) and $2$ of a third color. So that would be $14+3+2= 19$ balls.  That'd be possible if the $20$th ball was the only one of a fourth color.

If we try using $156=13\cdot 12$ we'd have $13$ balls of a color and $7$ remaining balls that must combine to $190-156=34$.  $7 = 7+0$ but that'd give us $7\cdot 6=42> 34$ which is too high.  $7 = 6+1$ which gives us $6\times 5=30$ which is too low.  $7=5+2$ gives us $20 + 2=22$ which is too low and $7=4+3\implies 12 + 6$ and $7=3+3+1 \implies 6+6$ and $7=2+2+2+1 \implies 2+2+2$ which are all too small.    So we can't do it with $13$ balls of one color.

If we try using $132=12\times 11$ we'd have $12$ balls of a color and out of $8$ remaining balls we must get a sum that adds to $190-132=58$.  We can't do $56+2$ because $56$ requires all $8$ remaining balls.  We can't do $42+x$ because $42$ requires $7$ of the remaining $8$ balls and we can't get a pair with only one ball.  We can't use $30+x$ because that requires $6$ balls and we only have $2$ left which can only give us $2$.  If we try $20+x$ have $5$ balls of one color and $3$ left and the most we can get with $3$ is $3\cdot 2=6$.  If we have $4$ balls of a color and for remaining the most we can get is $4\times 3 + 4\times 3$.

(We can observe by quasi AM-GM that the highest number we can get from $x$ balls is $x(x-1)$.  If we break it into any $x= j+k$ then $j(j-1) + k(k-1) < x(x-1)$)

If we try it for $110 = 11\times 10$ where we have $9$ remaining balls and we need to get $190-110 = 80$, we can't do it.  If we use all $9$ balls we can get $72$ which is too small.  And by the quasi AM-GM we observed if $j+k = 9; j,k\ge 1$ then $j(j-1) + k(k-1) < 72$.

If we try it for $90=10\times 9$ where we have $10$ remaining balls the must we can get of the remaining $10$ balls is $90$ and $90+90 =180$ is not high enough.

And with handwaving and arguing with ourselves and barking up trees, we can convince us we can't get it with any other combinations as breaking $20 = m + n +k$ where $m,n,k < 10$ we will always get $m(m-1) + n(n-1) + k(k-1) < 190$.

So it would seem the only way to do it is to have $14$ of one color, $3$ of a second, $2$ of a third, and $1$ of a fourth.